# MobiScroll's Agenda Synchronized Views free Alternative

Tags: reactjs, npm, calendar, microsoft-teams

I want to have an npm or free version of the above listed mobiscroll's Agenda Synchronized view.

I would like to show the Upcoming events of the current month or by clicking on the Date in the Calendar.

Something Like this.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.